# How can I control inputs using turtle library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm making a simple bow and arrow game in python using turtle library, and I want to be able to shoot the arrow on command and modify its initial speed and angle with keyboard inputs. However, I'm not being able to fire the arrow on command. My code is this:

```html
import math
import turtle
import time
import keyboard
import pygame

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Tiro al blanco")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width = 800, height = 600)
wn.tracer(0)

#parametros optimos: vi = 14.5, th = 45

vi = 14.5
th = 45

segs = 0
score = 0

fireStatus = 0

#dibujar target
target = turtle.Turtle()
target.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
target.shape("circle")
target.color("white")
target.shapesize(stretch_wid = 3, stretch_len = 3) 
target.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
target.goto(350,0) ##posición inicial

target2 = turtle.Turtle()
target2.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
target2.shape("circle")
target2.color("red")
target2.shapesize(stretch_wid = 2, stretch_len = 2) 
target2.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
target2.goto(350,0) ##posición inicial

target3 = turtle.Turtle()
target3.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
target3.shape("circle")
target3.color("white")
target3.shapesize(stretch_wid = 1, stretch_len = 1) 
target3.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
target3.goto(350,0) ##posición inicial

target4 = turtle.Turtle()
target4.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
target4.shape("circle")
target4.color("red")
target4.shapesize(stretch_wid = 0.5, stretch_len = 0.5) 
target4.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
target4.goto(350,0) ##posición inicial


#dibujar arco
bow = turtle.Turtle()
bow.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
bow.shape(turtle.circle(20,180))
bow.color("brown")
bow.shapesize(stretch_wid = 5, stretch_len = 1) 
bow.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
bow.goto(-350,0) ##posición inicial


#dibujar flecha
arrow = turtle.Turtle()
arrow.speed(0) #Velocidad de animacion, no de movimiento
arrow.shape("arrow")
arrow.color("cyan")
arrow.penup() ##Para que no trace línea de movimiento
arrow.goto(-350,0) ##posición inicial

arrow.velx = vi*math.cos(math.radians(th))

arrow.vely = vi*math.sin(math.radians(th))


#scoreboard
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("Score: 0", align = "center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

#parametros
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, -260)
pen.write("Velocidad:{}, Inclinacion: {} ".format(vi, th), align = "center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))


def fire(): #comando para cambiar el estado de disparo
  fireStatus = 1
  print(fireStatus)

turtle.onkey(fire, "space")

while True:
  fireStatus = 0
  wn.update()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  turtle.listen()
  print(fireStatus)
  segs +=1 
  #turtle.exitonclick()

  while fireStatus == True:
    arrow.vely = vi*math.sin(math.radians(th)) - 0.3*(segs)

    if arrow.ycor() < -100:
     arrow.vely = 0
     arrow.velx = 0

    if arrow.ycor() > 275:
      arrow.vely = 0
      arrow.velx = 0


    if arrow.xcor() > 335:
      arrow.vely = 0
      arrow.velx = 0


    if arrow.xcor() >= 330:
      if arrow.xcor() <= 350:
        if arrow.ycor() >= -30:
          if arrow.ycor() <= 30:
            arrow.vely = 0
            arrow.velx = 0
            score +=1
            pen.clear()
            time.sleep(3)
            arrow.goto(-350,0)
    arrow.setx(arrow.xcor() + arrow.velx)
    arrow.sety(arrow.ycor() + arrow.vely)
```

The problem is that the animation part of the code should only run if fireStatus=1, but if I try to force-assign fireStatus equal to 1, it doesn't run anyway. Also, I put a print(fireStatus) to see how it's changing, and it seems that the spacebar is actually mapped to calling the fire() function, however, something else seems to be assigning fireStatus = 0 because when I press my spacebar the print(fireStatus) alternates between 0 and 1.

However, since I'm gonna be modifying other internal variables via in-game input (inital speed), I should know if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: The `fireStatus` that you are assigning and printing inside `fire()` is a *local variable*, completely unrelated to the global variable of the same name that you are using elsewhere.  You would need a `global fireStatus` declaration inside that function in order to affect the global variable.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you! This solved the issue of the alternating 1s and 0s, however, now when fireStatus = 1, the program crashes. Any guesses?

Comment: Once you enter the `while fireStatus == True:` loop, there is nothing that can set the variable back to False.  Perhaps that should be an `if` instead of a `while`?

Comment: Why `import pygame`? `while True:` is unsuitable for a realtime game. Prefer `ontimer`.

Comment: @ggorlen tried something with pygame and didn't end up using it. Thanks!

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you! changing the while for an if made the issue go away.